# NBFFICallback with Win32 types raising type unresolved

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am currently exploring `NativeBoost`. Thought i will start with a simple event hook. For defining the callback i subclassed `NBFFICallback` and added my fnSpec with a return type of `LRESULT`.

```
fnSpec
    ^ 'LRESULT ( INT nCode, LPARAM lParam , WPARAM wParam)'
```

after i instantiated it using

```
mycallback := MyCallback on: someBlock.
```

which gives me an error with `Unable to resolve external type:`  at  `NBFFICallout >> resolveType: aTypeName`

Here i find that the binding of the type are being looked up from the `requestor` which is nil so it will look up from the class itself which is `NBNativeFunctionGen` and so the type wont be resolved.

Somehow i believe that if the type is resolved i will be able to create the callback and then pass it to my hook function. am i right?

Also, Should it be right to somehow (without touching the actual NB code) take my Object where i have shared pools referring to the Win32 types (NBWinTypes)  as the `requestor` and make the types get resolved that way?

In a nutshell how to add specific types to the callback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, I do not have a windows machine at hand to check, but those types are defined in **NBWinTypes** shared pool

So, I think you should include it as a poolDictionary in the class using the ffi call.

```
Object subclass: #MyClass
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    poolDictionaries: 'NBWinTypes'
    category: 'NativeBoost-Win32'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The requestor is the instance of NBNativeFunctionGen  , so unless i add the NBWinTypes in its shared pool i dont think it will be of use. Or else i will have to somehow change the requestor to MyCallback (somehow) instance , so it might work. But i am not sure that i am adhering to the best practices intented....